# Confusing election eligibility summary on the right side pane

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

https://stackoverflow.com/election

On the right, it says...

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 3,000 reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

...but apparently you must also have some badges (see the body)...

> ...an eligible candidate for the election must have all of the following badges: 
>   Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention

Also there is no mention of the needed reputation in the body, so you kinda have to read both, even though it may, of course, be self explanatory for those who're eligible for nomination.

I find this is a little confusing. Do you think this should be changed or is there a reason why it's been set up this way?

Answer (score 7):

I vote we change it to something like this (note that Stack Overflow is the only site that has badge requirements):

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than 3,000 reputation, and required badges, may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

In the bottom bar, we should make it clear when you don't have the required badges - ideally **indicating which ones are missing**. I'm a fan of how http://elections.stackexchange.com shows this:

[image]

We could do the same thing on the election page.

Comment: It would also be helpful if the badges that count toward the candidate score and those listed on http://elections.stackexchange.com/ were the same. For example, Outspoken is not one of the ones that matters to candidate score. That can be a little confusing.

Comment: @EdCottrell Agreed.

Comment: @EdCottrell Will look into tweaking that, thanks!